# T-SQL short-circuit alternative

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query whereby I am passing a "@userID" and a Y/N parameter called "@onlyMine"
Basically, if @OnlyMine = 'Y' then I want to pull records based on the @UserId passed
Otherwise, I want to pull all records.

I tried this:

```
WHERE
...
AND (( @OnlyMine= 'N') OR ( UserId = @UserId ))
...
```

But after reading how short-circuiting is not reliable this doesn't work.
( or maybe the logic is just wrong )

Also, doing something like

```
IF @OnlyMine = 'Y'
   SELECT...
ELSE
   SELECT...
END
```

Isn't viable since I have roughly 15 clauses like this.
Each appending to the WHERE clause based on a variable passed.

Any guidance on how to go about formatting the statement to achieve this?

Comment: Your first attempt is how this is normally done.

Comment: If its not working please provide additional information i.e. a [mre]

Comment: If this is in a stored procedure or function and you care about performance, you are probably safest recompiling the query on every call.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your code in theory. But sometimes, having so many conditions may effect the performance if in order to apply the conditions a lot of data sources are queried. Also, complex T-SQL statements might be difficult for the engine to optimize.

An alternative of your technique is to apply additional validations before touching the data and dynamic T-SQL.

For example, first you can check if data should be returned at all. Let's say that the user `wants to see all data`, but `does not required access`. Instead if joining the various table and returning nothing, you can have something like that:

```
If @OnlyMine= 'N' AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.SecurityGroupsMembers WHERE [userID] = @current_user_id AND [groupID] IN (groups who can read the data))
BEGIN;
    (return empty result set)
END;
```

Identifying such cases and getting the empty result can be good for the user experience. I have seen a lot of cases, where the user is waiting 10-20 or more seconds and than a empty table is rendered because of complex queries returning nothing.

Second, you can use dynamic T-SQL statement. For example:

```
DECLARE @DynamicTSQLStatement NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @DynamicTSQLStatement = 'SELECT * FROM Users WHERE .... '

SET @DynamicTSQLStatement = @DynamicTSQLStatement + IIF(@OnlyMine = 'Y', ' AND UserId = @UserId', '')

EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicTSQLStatement , parameters...
```

So, if user what's personal data only, filter by the id, other wise, do not include this filtering criteria at all.

Of course, the above will add more complexity to user stored procedure. If you have not got any performances issues you are save with your initial code.